# How to reference resources not within the Jar file?

Tags: java, resources, executable-jar

I have a Java project that uses some resource files. I want to bundle up the project into a jar file but I need to still be able to reference the resource files. I don't want these resources to be bundled into the jar as the end users need to be able to make changes to them.

So is there a way to have the jar file look for the resources within the directory that contains the jar? Not within the jar itself?

So something like below, where the jar file refers to the files contained within the resources directory:

```
C:/MyDirectory/
   |- project.jar
   |- resources/
       |- resourceFile.txt
```

Comment: what about `java.nio.file.Path` and/or `java.io.File`?

Comment: better IMHO: `URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("resources/resourceFile.txt");` (works for resources in directory, assuming correct `Class-Path` entry in `manifest.mf` **and** in the JAR file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String myGreatResourceLocation = "c://MyDirectory/resources/resourceFile.txt";

java.nio.file.Path myGreatResource = java.nio.file.Paths.get( myGreatResourceLocation );
```

So you can access your resource's data using `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines()`, there are other available methods also. If you are just reading to get a String, `readAllLines()` will be great, since it allows you to specify the character set, which will save you from later headaches.

Notice however that, if someone use your jar file into a web application, it usually won't be able to read your data (you'll have to check the documentation for your web or application server)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what if their resources are not kept in a location the same as mine? So mine would be in a directory like `c://users/SamX/resources` and theirs is in `c://users/Bob/resources`

Comment: That's a different question, but several of the topics you need to grasp are already covered at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html, (You will use System.getProperty("user.home") for that).

Comment: Also, please take special care to better use the "file.separator" System property to compose the location string, for production code (already covered at the shared link also).

Comment: Great, thank you very much. That helps a lot. The system properties user.home and user.dir is exactly what I needed.

Comment: to have a path relative to working (starting) directory use `Path.of("resources", "resourceFile.txt")` or `Paths.get("resources", "resourceFile.txt")` (absolute paths should only be used for fast testing or with care, if at all)